# How did they shoot the animal scenes in Life of Pi?

Tags: effects, life-of-pi, production

Is the tiger, hyena, zebra etc animated? They look quite real. Are they trained animals?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The film won the Academy Award for Best Visual Effects largely because that tiger looked so real.  Special effects supervisor Bill Westenhofer wrote in an [interview](http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/oscar-effects-how-life-of-pi-caught-a-digital-tiger-by-the-tail/) for Digital Trends

> “We used [real tigers] for single shots, where it was just the tiger in the frame, and they’re doing something that didn’t have to be all that specific in the action that we were after,” Westenhofer told The New York Times. “By doing that, it set our bar high for CGI. We couldn’t cheat at all. It pushed the artists to go and deliver something that’s never been done before, something as photo-real as anyone has ever done with an animal.”

Answer (score 6):

The answer is that both real animals and Computer Generated Imagery (CGI) were used.  Clearly in situations which will put an animal or an actor in danger, they will use CGI.

See this [article](http://www.nextmovie.com/blog/life-of-pi-tiger-cgi-or-real/).

Comment: What is the full form of CGI?

Comment: @TaxiDriver - added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

the answer is that the real tiger was almost killed, shooting the water scenes.
The "no animals were harmed in the making of this picture" stamp is a scam, AHA is not only ignoring the crime but helping cover it up.

- read it for yourself: http://www.theguardian.com/film/2013/nov/27/life-of-pi-tiger-nearly-drowned-report-animals-hollywood

*and the original email: http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/feature/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/LifeofPi-email.pdf

Comment: After reading the article, email, and several other linked articles, I am not convinced about the authenticity of this allegation nor the credibility of the email which is lacking quite a bit of information (signatures, headers, "RE:" but no original email being replied to, etc).